# validar caja de texto para que primer caracter sea una letra

Tags: javascript

Tengo un formulario en php para un registro de usuario, y estoy validando los input type text con javascript

Existe alguna funcion en javascript que haga que el primer caracter a ingresar en una caja de texto sea obligatoriamente una letra? por ahora tengo validacion a cajas de texto solo letras y solo numeros, tambien que la primera letra a introducir se coloque en mayuscula asi el usuario la coloque miniscula, pero quisiera validar una caja de texto a que cuando vayan a escribir, sea obligatorio al principio comenzar con una letra y ya luego si pueden ser numeros y asi. se puede?

para la validacion de numeros y letras hice lo siguiente:

```
function soloLetras(e) {
    key = e.keyCode || e.which;
    tecla = String.fromCharCode(key).toString();
    letras = " áéíóúabcdefghijklmnñopqrstuvwxyzÁÉÍÓÚABCDEFGHIJKLMNÑOPQRSTUVWXYZ";//Se define todo el abecedario que se quiere que se muestre.
    especiales = [8, 9, 37, 39, 46, 6]; //Es la validación del KeyCodes, que teclas recibe el campo de texto.

    tecla_especial = false
    for(var i in especiales) {
        if(key == especiales[i]) {
            tecla_especial = true;
            break;
        }
    }

    if(letras.indexOf(tecla) == -1 && !tecla_especial){
alert('Este campo solo permite letras');
        return false;
      }
}


function SoloNumeros(evt){
 if(window.event){//asignamos el valor de la tecla a keynum
  keynum = evt.keyCode; //IE
 }
 else{
  keynum = evt.which; //FF
 } 
 //comprobamos si se encuentra en el rango numérico y que teclas no recibirá.
 if((keynum > 47 && keynum < 58) || keynum == 8 || keynum == 13 || keynum == 6 ){
  return true;
 }
 else{
  return false;
 }
}
```

y para aplicarlo en las cajas de texto, les agregue siempre al final del required lo siguiente:

```
SI ES LETRAS ---> required onkeypress="return soloLetras(event);" onkeyup="this.value = this.value.charAt(0).toUpperCase() + this.value.slice(1);" class="mayusculas" maxlength="15"  

  SI ES NUMEROS--->  onKeyPress="return SoloNumeros(event);"
```

Ahora como quiero colocar un campo "direccion", deseo que el usuario al introducirla sea siempre una letra al principio y no un numero, por eso mi consulta.

Comment: Se puede. Por ejemplo, mira el evento `onChange` del input y vete evaluando el primer caracter que introduzcan. Si es letra, permitelo, si no, que no escriba. Prueba a implementar y si tienes dudas pregunta aqui. Un saludo

Comment: Te recomiendo que agregues un ejemplo de lo que hayas intentado

Comment: Rodrigo, te recomendamos que pongas un ejemplo, ya que hay muchas formas de hacer lo que dices. En SOes tratamos de resolver problemas especificos, y especialmente, de dar la respuesta que mejor te pueda ayudar. Asi que si pones lo que has intentando, sabremos que camino estas tomando y podras recibir la mejor respuesta.

Comment: @lois6b voy a chequear a ver que tal, gracias por tu respuesta.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Creo que esto es lo que buscas, lo que hace es contar cuantos caracteres tiene el input, si esta vacio permite meter letras, si ya es mayor que 1 te deja meter numeros.

Espero te sirva, saludos desde Honduras.

```js
  function soloLetras(e) {
    textoArea = document.getElementById("cajaTexto").value;
    var total = textoArea.length;
    if (total == 0) {
      key = e.keyCode || e.which;
      tecla = String.fromCharCode(key).toString();
      letras = " áéíóúabcdefghijklmnñopqrstuvwxyzÁÉÍÓÚABCDEFGHIJKLMNÑOPQRSTUVWXYZ"; //Se define todo el abecedario que se quiere que se muestre.
      especiales = [8, 9, 37, 39, 46, 6]; //Es la validación del KeyCodes, que teclas recibe el campo de texto.

      tecla_especial = false
      for (var i in especiales) {
        if (key == especiales[i]) {
          tecla_especial = true;
          break;
        }
      }

      if (letras.indexOf(tecla) == -1 && !tecla_especial) {
        return false;
        alert('No puedes comenzar escribiendo numeros');
      }
    }
  }

function SoloNumeros(evt) {
  if (window.event) { //asignamos el valor de la tecla a keynum
    keynum = evt.keyCode; //IE
  } else {
    keynum = evt.which; //FF
  }
  //comprobamos si se encuentra en el rango numérico y que teclas no recibirá.
  if ((keynum > 47 && keynum < 58) || keynum == 8 || keynum == 13 || keynum == 6) {
    return true;
  } else {
    return false;
  }
}
```

```html
<label>Letras</label> <input type="text" id="cajaTexto" required onkeypress="return soloLetras(event);" onkeyup="this.value = this.value.charAt(0).toUpperCase() + this.value.slice(1);" class="mayusculas" maxlength="15" ">

   <label>Numeros</label> <input onKeyPress="return SoloNumeros(event); "/>
```

Comment: Hola Luis, muchas gracias por tu respuesta. Esta ha sido la solucion exacta a mi consulta! muchas gracias por tu tiempo y tu apoyo. Saludos desde Venezuela.

Comment: Estamos para servir, saludos. @rodrigo2324

Answer (score 1):

```js
function check(){
var letra = /[a-z]/;
var d = document.getElementById("d").value;
var s = d.split("");  
if(letra.test(s[0]) == 0) console.info("No es letra");
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
  <title>JS Bin</title>
</head>
<body>
<input id="d" type="text" placeholder="Direccion"/>
<input type="button" value="Chequear" onclick="check()"/>
  </body>
</html>
```

***Con una expresión regular que regula si esta entre a-z, lo puedes hacer.***

Comment: Hola eduardo. Deberias explicar mejor como funciona tu codigo. Además no acepta letras con tilde como `"á"`. Un saludo

Comment: Hola Eduardo, y en ese caso como se podria hacer que en vez de que salga al darle al boton, sea apenas vaya a escribir el usuario la direccion para que salga la alerta? con onkeypress?